# Laravel Sanctum CSRF + NextJs 14 does'nt work

Tags: rest, next.js, laravel-10, laravel-sanctum, csrf-token

I am currently facing an issue with communication between my Laravel server and my Next.js frontend. When I send a request, such as a login request, I encounter a 419 error, which is related to CSRF.

Firstly, I want to mention that I conducted tests on the same Laravel server using a React frontend, and everything worked well. This leads me to the conclusion that the server is correctly configured and that the issue lies with Next.js.

Here is my Axios configuration in the **lib/axios.ts** file:

```
import Axios from "axios";

const axios = Axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL // = http://localhost:8000,
 headers: {
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
},
 withCredentials: true
});

export default axios;
```

Next, here is my authentication file in **hooks/auth.ts**:

```
import axios from "@/lib/axios";
   import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
   import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import useSWR from "swr";

   interface MiddlewareType {
     middleware?: string;
   }

   export const useAuth = ({middleware}: MiddlewareType = {}) => {

    const router = useRouter();

    // CSRF
    // const csrf = () => axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    const csrf = async (): Promise<any> => {
        const response = await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
          return response;
    }
    
    // User
    const {data: user, error, mutate} = useSWR("/api/user",
        () => axios
        .get("/api/user")
        .then(response => response.data.user)
        .catch(error => {
            if(error.response.status !== 409)
            throw error
        })
    );
    // Login
    const login = async({setErrors, ...props}: any) => {
        setErrors([]);
        await csrf();
  
        await axios.post('/login', props)
        .then(() => mutate() && router.push("/dashboard"))
        .catch(error => {
            if(error.response.status !== 422) throw error
            setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
        })
    }
    return {
        user,
        csrf,
        login,
    }
}
```

Finally, I send my values to the login function from my LoginPage:

```
  const {login, user} = useAuth({middleware: "guest"});
  const onSubmit = async(values: z.infer<typeof loginSchema>) => {
  console.log(values)
  const email = values.email;
  const password = values.password;

  login({setErrors, email, password});
 }
```

Every time, I encounter a 419 error on the post("/login"). As I mentioned, when I try it with my React app, the token is recognized and functional.

Is there a compatibility issue between Next.js 14 and Laravel?

PS: I use next-intl as middleware for translating my site. Could this be related to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` request will set a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie in your browser.

Every non-reading request (post/put/patch/delete) you make must include that token value as a `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header so that your request gets past the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

Made a short video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bN0cijg_LJU